i want to understand why this comparison isn't working in javascript
i have an if statement in JavaScript, the problem (was its fixed now but I don't know why)
when the parameters are val1 and val2 as objects, this Code works:
if (typeof(val1) === typeof(val2) === 'object' && val1 !== null && val2 !== null) 

but this Code does :
 if (typeof(val1) === 'object' && typeof(val2) === 'object' && val1 !== null && val2 !== null)

How is
typeof(val1) === 'object' && typeof(val2) === 'object' 

difrente from :
typeof(val1) === typeof(val2) === 'object'

i treid to ask chat gpt this is the answer and it worked but i want to know why

It looks like the issue is with how the comparisons are structured. The expression typeof(val1) === typeof(val2) === 'object' doesn't work as intended because it evaluates left to right. Instead, try breaking it down like this:
if (typeof(val1) === 'object' && typeof(val2) === 'object' && val1 !== null && val2 !== null) {



You cannot chain together comparisons like that in JavaScript; it does not work the way you think it will. It won't produce errors, but it will almost certainly mean something to JavaScript that is completely different from what you intended.

Step 1.  compute typeof val1 and typeof val2 and compare them.  result - true or false
Step 2.  Take result and compare with string "object".  always false since "object" does not equal true or false.

Did you mean to say that the first code does not work?

you are confusing syntactic systems, one belongs to Boolean algebra, the other only exists for human and non-ergative languages.

Because of operator precedence and associativity
typeof(val1) === typeof(val2) === 'object'

is equivalent to
(typeof(val1) === typeof(val2)) === 'object'

This first evaluates typeof(val1) === typeof(val2), which returns either true or false. Neither of these can be equal to the string 'object', so the whole condition is always false.

Very logic code reads from left to right, so the first 2 are evaluated then compared with the following

It's not always left to right. Some operators are right-associative. See the precedence table I linked to.

Yes @Barmar I just did :-) and you are right

typeof(val1) === 'object' && typeof(val2) === 'object'

typeof(val1) === typeof(val2) === 'object'

in the first case we get a boolean && boolean which must be true for the condition to be satisfied.
in the second case we compare "object" with "object" and get boolean true, and then compare it with string and get false.
if (typeof(val1) === typeof(val2) === 'object' && val1 !== null &&
val2 !== null)

here we get first true -> false && true or false && true or false
if you want to understand, study data types and typeScript

This is because I am from Russia and used Google translator
